# Authentication/Authorization implement in pyramid

Tags: python, security, pyramid

I have follow the documentation [Group-Level Security](http://michael.merickel.org/projects/pyramid_auth_demo/group_security.html)
write these:

```
def groupfinder(userid, request):
    print '#'*80
    print userid
    role = DBSession.query(Role)....

    if role.name == "Admin":
        return ['g:admin']


class RootFactory(object):
        __acl__ = [
            (Allow, Everyone, 'view'),
            (Allow, Authenticated, 'edit'),
            (Allow, 'g:admin', 'admin')
        ]

        def __init__(self, request):
            pass


authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(
    settings['auth.secret'],
    callback=groupfinder,
)
```

it worked, but every page loaded it query the DB repeatedly
shoud it be just return the permission first time when user login?
or maybe I'm doing the wrong way...

and how do I know the permission "g:admin" in templates like mako

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `groupfinder` has a subtle bug right now. It should always return a list if the user is valid. Only if there is no user should it return `None`. Right now you only return a list if the user is an admin, so normal users will never be recognized.

```
def groupfinder(userid, request):
    print '#'*80
    print userid
    role = DBSession.query(Role)....

    if role is not None:
        principals = []
        if role.name == "Admin":
            principals.append('g:admin')
        return principals
```

Notice how we always return a list, unless `role` is `None`.

Next, you asked about performance. Pyramid doesn't attempt to cache anything. You can, however, handle this easily yourself. The typical way of doing this is adding a cached (reified) property on your `request` object that contains the `role` or `user`. That way every time the `groupfinder` is invoked, you'll use the cached `role` instead of querying for it again. This pattern is demonstrated [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/auth/user_object.html).

> how do I know the permission "g:admin" in templates like mako

Well 'g:admin' is actually a *principal* in the authentication jargon of Pyramid. 'admin' (the third element of your access control entry) is the *permission*. Principals are treated as an implementation detail that just helps us map things to permissions. In the end we really just care about the permission when dealing with access/authorization.

To see if a user has that permission in your template you can use `pyramid.security.has_permission('admin', request.context, request)`. You can replace `request.context` with any object that has an `__acl__` on it, but `request.context` will be your `RootFactory` in this scenario (which is what you want).